# Conditionally including minified or full libraries or plugins for debugging JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: jquery, debugging, jquery-plugins, conditional-statements, javascript

Is there a best way to conditionally use either the minified or full version of JavaScript frameworks, libraries, and plugins depending on whether you're debugging or not etc?

jQuery specific answers are good, but so too are pure JavaScript answers considering that you might very well want to conditionally include the minified vs full version of jQuery itself.

Also, what if there are more than two choices? Say minified vs full versions *and* [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) vs locally stored?

Comment: It may not be of any use to you, but ASP.Net MVC 4 does this automatically based on the build type (Release or Debug)